# D'où provient le sens « qualifier » du verbe « taxer » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, histoire

En lisant pour un cours portant sur la Santé et sécurité au travail, je suis tombé sur la phrase suivante:

> Les journaux de l'époque **taxaient** les demandes syndicales de communisme.

Après quelque recherche sur ce mot, je suis arrivé sur la [page Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/taxer) du verbe *taxer* et j'ai bien compris qu'il était utilisé dans le sens du verbe *qualifier*.

Mais, en regardant les autres sens de « taxer », j'ai remarqué qu'ils sont plus proche des verbes « imposer », « soumettre à une taxe », « voler », etc. Ça concorde bien avec le fait qu'historiquement, les seigneurs pouvaient *soumettre à une taxe très élevé* (voler) les citoyens/paysans qui pouvaient être, même avant de voir leurs revenus *imposés*, déjà pas très riche...

L'utilisation du verbe « taxer » dans le sens de « qualifier » a t-elle aussi une provenance historique ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il y a deux verbes **taxer** qui ont une étymologie et un sens différents.

**Taxer** dans le sens de « **soumettre à une taxe** », « imposer » vient du du grec *tassein* (ranger, fixer) qui a donné le latin *taxare* (imposer, évaluer, estimer). On le trouve en ancien français sous les formes de *tauxer* et *tausser*. (D'après *le Dictionnaire culturel en langue française*)

> Le mot a d'abord eu le sens de « régler les frais de justice, les amendes  » (1247) [...] Il a pris ensuite d'autres valeurs, « faire payer une taxe à quelqu'un (1471) et « mettre un impôt sur quelque chose » (1690). (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*)

On retrouve cette racine dans le préfixe taxi- (taxidermie, taxinomie,...) qui donne l'idée d’arrangement, d'ordre. Et le mot a donné *taximètre* (compteur horokilométrique) qui lui même a donné le mot *taxi* (véhicule).

**Taxer** au sens de « **blâmer, attaquer** » est apparu au 16<sup>e</sup> siècle et vient du latin *taxare* forme fréquentative de *tangere* (toucher)<sup>1</sup>. On le trouve avec ce sens dans Molière :

> Ce que j'en dis n'est pas pour taxer votre office. (Molière, *l'École des maris*)

> Ce sens d'accuser a cessé d'être employé en construction directe, mais reste vivant dans la construction indirecte taxer (*qqn. qqch.*) *de*.
>   [...] Pour cet emploi on passe de l'idée de blâmer à la valeur neutre de qualifier. (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*)

> Toute musique qui voulait dire quelque chose était taxée d'impure. (Romain Rolland, *Jean-Christophe*, 1904 - 19012).

<sup>1</sup> La même racine latine a donné le mot « tangente ».

Comment: et aussi "tangible" dont le sens est plus proche.

Answer (score 2):

Selon le [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/taxer), le deuxième sens de taxer (blâmer, accuser) est issu du latin taxare :

> Étymol. et Hist.
>
> 1. a) 1247 tauxer « régler les frais de justice, les amendes » (doc. ds Runk., p. 99); xiiies. tausser « évaluer, estimer à sa valeur » (Poire, 53 ds T.-L.); ca 1260 tausier « id. » (Ménestrel Reims, 435, ibid.); 1283 tausser « id. » (Philippe de Beaumanoir, Coutumes Beauvaisis, éd. A. Salmon, 26, 986, 1100, 1513); b) 1271-72 taxer « id. » (doc. de La Rochelle ds Z. fr. Spr. Lit. t. 84, p. 345); 1464 taxer « fixer la taxe à payer par quelqu'un » (doc. ds Bartzsch, p. 99); 1679 « régler officiellement le prix d'une denrée » (Rich.); 1690 taxer (qqc.) « mettre un impôt (sur quelque chose) » (Fur.);
> 2. 1538 « blâmer, accuser » (Est.). Empr. au lat.taxare « toucher souvent et fortement; blâmer, reprendre, estimer, évaluer », lui-même empr. au gr. τ α ́ σ σ ε ι ν « ranger, fixer » (pour l'hist. de taxare, v. en partic. Ern.-Meillet). La forme taxer a évincé tausser (v. taxation).